# Maximum contiguous sub-array (With most number of elements)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

Given an array of natural numbers and an another natural T, how to find the contiguous subarray with sum less than or equal to T but the number of element in this subarray is maximized?

For example, if the given array is:

`{3, 1, 2, 1, 1}` and `T = 5`. Then the maximum contigous subarray is `{1, 2, 1, 1}` because it will contain 5 elements and the sum is equal to 5.

Another example: `{10,1,1,1,1,3,6,7}` with `T = 8`. Then the maximum contigous subarray is `${1,1,1,1,3}$`

I can do it with `O(n^2)` operation. However I am looking for a linear time solution for this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: To me it seems a version of the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ought to be possible to do this with O(n). I've not tested this, but it looks OK:

```
int start = 0, end = 0;
int beststart = 0, bestend = 0;
int sum = array[0];

while (end + 1 < arraysize) {
  if (array[end + 1] + sum <= T)
    sum += array[end++];
  else
    sum -= array[start++];
  if ((end - start) > (bestend - beststart)) {
    beststart = start;
    bestend = end;
  }
}
```

So, basically, it moves a sliding window along the array and records the point at which `end  - start` is the greatest.

Comment: I think you need another check ` if ((end - start) > (bestend - beststart)) {
      beststart = start;
      bestend = end;
    }` at the end.

Comment: @Quixotic: is that better now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a capped version of the Maximum subarray problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem
I guess you can find inspirations with existing algorithms.